# How to minimize that expression in four variables?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I mean
$\sqrt{w^2+(21-x)^2}+\sqrt{(20-w)^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(20-y)^2}+\sqrt{y^2+(21-z)^2}.$

The command

```
Minimize[Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] + 
Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2], {x, y, z, w}]
```

is running without any response on my comp for hours. The numerical optimizations

```
NMinimize[ Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] + 
Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2], {x, y, z, w}, 
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{58., {x -> 11.579, y -> 8.97237, z -> 11.579, w -> 8.97237}`

and the same with `Method->"RandomSearch"`

> `{58., {x -> 10.5551, y -> 9.94753, z -> 10.5551, w -> 9.94753}}`

and the same with `Method->"NelderMead"`

> `{58., {x -> 18.3218, y -> 2.55062, z -> 18.3218, w -> 2.55062}}`

suggest the optimal value under consideration is taken in many points.

Comment: Maple 2021 answers $\{x=-\frac{21 w}{20}+21,y=w,z=-\frac{21 w}{20}+21,w=w,\,\,\,\,\\,\,\,\,\sqrt{x^{2}+(20-y)^{2}}+\sqrt{y^{2}+(21-z)^{2}}+\sqrt{z^{2}+(20-w)^{2}}+\sqrt{w^{2}+(21-x)^{2}}=58\}$.

Comment: The minimum is achieved on a 1 dimensional subspace of R4. Therefore, numerical routines can get different answers, depending on the methods and working precision.

Comment: The Maple result indicates that the min value of `58` is obtained for any `w` in the interval `{0, 20}`; the other variables will vary accordingly.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: `Reduce[Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] + 
    Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2] == 
   58 /. {x -> -21 w/20 + 21, y -> w, z -> -21 w/20 + 21}, w, Reals]` evaluates to `0<=w<=20`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the recently released Mathematica 12.3 this works faster (using newly added convex optimization methods).

```
In[1]:= Minimize[Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] + Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2], {x, y, z, w}] // AbsoluteTiming // InputForm                                           

Out[1]//InputForm= {2.204591, {58, {x -> 21/2, y -> 10, z -> 21/2, w -> 10}}}
```

Comment: It would be nice if `Minimize` could indicate the non-uniqueness of an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is its proof known to me. The expression `Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] +  Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2]` is nothing but the length of the broken line
between the points `{0,0},{x,20-y},{x+21-z,20},{x+21,40-w},{42,40}`. It's clear its length is greater than or equal to
the distance between the points `{0,0}` and `{42,40}` which equals `58`. Unfortunately, the command

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x,y,z,w},Sqrt[x^2 + (20 - y)^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (21 - z)^2] + 
Sqrt[z^2 + (20 - w)^2] + Sqrt[w^2 + (21 - x)^2] >=58],Reals]
```

is running without any response on my comp for hours as well as the command with `EucledeanDistance` instead of `Sqrt`.